# Ruby on Rails .where DateTime does not respect '<'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, sqlite

I'm doing a RESTFul app using Ruby on Rails(Server-side) and iOS6(Client-side). The communication is done using JSON.

```
@notifications = @update[:notifications]
    if @notifications
      @last_id = @notifications[:last_id]
      @last_update = @notifications[:last_update]
      @new_notif = OrgNotification.where('id > ?',@last_id)
      @updated_notif = OrgNotification.where('updated_at != ?',@last_update )..where('id <= ? AND ? < updated_at',@last_id,@last_update )
end
```

In this code I want to put in the @updated_notif variable, all the notifications that have a smaller id that the last one that I already saw and an update_at which is after the one how is passed in [:last_update].
My problem is that in the case that both dates are equal, I'm getting that row.

I've tried:

```
OrgNotification.where('id <= ? AND ? < updated_at',@last_id,@last_update ).where('updated_at NOT IN (?)', @last_update)
OrgNotification.where('id <= ? AND ? < updated_at',@last_id,@last_update ).where('updated_at != ?', @last_update)
OrgNotification.where('id <= ? AND ? < updated_at AND updated_at != ?',@last_id,@last_update,@last_update )
```

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT "org_notifications".* FROM "org_notifications" WHERE (id <= '2' AND '2013-06-02 21:04:13 UTC' < updated_at) AND (updated_at NOT IN ('2013-06-02 21:04:13 UTC'))
```

It works fine if the date is different, either smaller or bigger.
How can I solve this? Any thing I could try?

Thanks

EDIT

I went to the db from the terminal and saw this.

2013-06-02 21:04:13.834167|2013-06-02 21:04:13.834167

My problem is in the precision. How can i send this precision to my client?

I've tried .to_r, .to_a, .to_s.

```
        "updated_at": <%= notif.updated_at{here} %>
```

It can go as a string because i only use it to compare on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an instance of `Notification` called `notif`, try

```
notif.updated_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N')
```